# Understanding the meaning of a topology being weaker than another.

Tags: general-topology

In topology, a topology $T_1$ is said to be weaker than another $T_2$ if $T_1$ is contained in $T_2$. The reason for "weaker" is that there could be more convergent sequences in $T_1$ than in $T_2$, but I cannot understand this. I tried to study a simple example, for instance, $X=\left\{1,2\right\}$ with $T_1=\left\{\emptyset, \left\{1\right\}, X\right\}$ and $T_2=\left\{\emptyset, \left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},X\right\}$, but I don't know if it's an effective example (I don't know how to see if they have the same number of convergent sequences, etc.). Is there a simple example that I can use to understand this? Thanks.

Comment: If you know some probability, then you can make it analogous with the conditional expectation. More complex the filtration is more information it contains, in the sense  that more precise conditional expectation it can generate. For topology, the idea is similar, it contains more 'information' so more complicated continuous function can be constructed.

Comment: Any continuous function $f:(X,T_1)\to Y$ is also continuous as a function $(X,T_2)\to Y,$ but not visa versa. So there are more continuous functions from $(X,T_2),$ which we can say means it is "easier" to be continuous on $T_2.$

Comment: I would add: It is generally a bad idea to consider sequences as somehow being the key to envisioning topologies. There is a reason general topology uses "nets" rather than sequences. Sequences make sense in a limited class of topologies - including metric spaces.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews worth mentioning that sequences/convergence make sense in any topology. They do seem less intuitive (sometimes counterintuitive) in non-metrizable spaces (not sure if algebraic geometers would agree). They also just don't come up as much as an intro topology course might suggest.

Comment: Also — and I'm not sure if this is directly related to your question or not — terms like "stronger" and "weaker" are subjective. The trivial topology on $X$ is strong if you want functions $Y\to X$ to be continuous, but weak if you want functions $X\to Y$ to be continuous. The words "strong" and "weak" only really make sense if you have some goal in mind.

Comment: Yeah, they make sense, but they aren't the core of how we think about topological spaces, which is in terms of continuous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you can easily check by definition of the convergence with respect to a given topology that:

On the one hand,

- An X-valued sequence $T_2$-converges to 1 iff it is constant equal to 1 except for finitely many terms;
- An X-valued sequence $T_1$-converges to 1 iff it is constant equal to 1 except for finitely many terms.
  Therefore, $T_2$-convergence to 1 is equivalent to $T_1$-convergence to 1.

On the other hand,

- An X-valued sequence $T_2$-converges to 2 iff it is constant equal to 2 except for finitely many terms;
- Any X-valued sequence $T_1$-converges to 2.
  Therefore, $T_2$-convergence implies $T_1$-convergence but the converse does not hold.

There are more $T_1$-convergent sequences than $T_2$-convergent sequences.

Comment: I think I understood. Element 2 has only one neighborhood, the neighborhood V={1,2}, so any net converges to 2 since every number in the net is in {1,2}.

Answer (score 0):

Any continuous function $f:(X,T_1)\to Y$ is also continuous as a function $(X,T_2)\to Y,$ but not visa versa.

So there are more continuous functions from $(X,T_2),$ which we can intuitively say makes it "easier" to be continuous on $T_2.$

In your specific case, with $X=\{1,2\},$ all functions are continuous on $T_2.$

On $T_1,$ $f$ is continuous iff any open set in $Y$ containing $f(2)$ also contains $f(1).$

---

On the other hand, any map $Y\to X$ which is continuous to $T_2$ is continuous to $T_1.$ So it is easier to be continuous to a weaker topology.